# Is there a possibility to draw a vertical line to the right of a horizontal line?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'll make it short and simple. What I'm trying to do is this :

[image]

Right now, I've this :

[image]

Here is the code :

```css
#ligne_horizontale_experience {
    margin-left: 50px;
    width:170px; 
    height:400px;
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #707070;
}

#ligne_verticale_experience_1 {
    margin-left: 50px;
    width:45px; 
    height: 0px;
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    border-color: transparent transparent #707070 transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name ="author" content="me">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="code.css">
    <title>me</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <p class="h6">Professionnel</p>
                <div id="ligne_horizontale_experience"></div>
                <div id="ligne_verticale_experience_1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm strunggling trying to do this since couple hours..

Cordially,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with background:

```css
#ligne_horizontale_experience {
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 400px;
  border-left: solid 1px #707070;
  /* 5 lines with 1px height */
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(transparent 0 calc(100%/5 - 1px),#707070 0 calc(100%/5));
}
```

```html
<p class="h6">Professionnel</p>
<div id="ligne_horizontale_experience"></div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. I have one more question about this. If I want to add a picture with some text on the right of every vertical line, how can I do that with your solution ?

Comment: @Balaure I would probably need another code, You didn't add such requirement to the question so I didn't consider it